# React Native atob() / btoa() not working without remote JS debugging

Tags: react-native

I have a testing app in react native, and all works fine when I have enabled the debug js remotely. It works fine in device (from XCode) and simulator, after run:

```
react-native run ios
```

The problem is that if I stop remote js debugging, the login test not works anymore.The login logic is very simple, I'm making a fetch to an api to test a login, the API endpoint is over https.

What I need to change?

**Updated: This code works perfetly with JS Debug Remote Enabled, if I disable it, it not works anymore.**

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,      
  View,
  Button,
  Alert
} from 'react-native'

export default class MyClass extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.testFetch = this.testFetch.bind(this)
  }

  async testFetch () {
    const email = 'email@example.com'
    const password = '123456'

    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://www.example.com/api/auth/login', {
        /* eslint no-undef: 0 */
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json' /* eslint quote-props: 0 */,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(email + ':' + password)
        }

      })
      Alert.alert('Error fail!', 'Fail')
      console.log(response)
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('Error response!', 'Ok')
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>            
        <Button
          onPress={this.testFetch}
          title="Test me!"

        />            
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5
  }
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('testingReactNative', () => MyClass)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need at least to add some code here. JS remote debugging is unlikely to cause this error.

Comment: Hi @zvona I have updated the question with code... thanks.

Comment: Ok, my error is that "btoa" is undefined when execute it without debug... but why? :)

Comment: Oh, good catch. `atob` and `btoa` does not work without debugger (can't explain why).

Comment: I'll write you Base64 `atob` / `btoa` functions to use and answer.

Comment: Just same as this issue,you will not allowed use some es6 features react native don't support but chrome did,when you connect your react-native app to chrome remote debugger you change the js runtime environment to chrome.this's why you can't use some features without remote debugger and polyfills are solutions.

Comment: i had the same issue, all the answers solution work fine but in Release apk it doesn't work. any Idea??

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Here you go (https://sketch.expo.io/BktW0xdje). Create a separate component (e.g. **Base64.js**), import it and it's ready to use. For instance `Base64.btoa('123');`

```
// @flow
// Inspired by: https://github.com/davidchambers/Base64.js/blob/master/base64.js

const chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';
const Base64 = {
  btoa: (input:string = '')  => {
    let str = input;
    let output = '';

    for (let block = 0, charCode, i = 0, map = chars;
    str.charAt(i | 0) || (map = '=', i % 1);
    output += map.charAt(63 & block >> 8 - i % 1 * 8)) {

      charCode = str.charCodeAt(i += 3/4);

      if (charCode > 0xFF) {
        throw new Error("'btoa' failed: The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.");
      }

      block = block << 8 | charCode;
    }

    return output;
  },

  atob: (input:string = '') => {
    let str = input.replace(/=+$/, '');
    let output = '';

    if (str.length % 4 == 1) {
      throw new Error("'atob' failed: The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.");
    }
    for (let bc = 0, bs = 0, buffer, i = 0;
      buffer = str.charAt(i++);

      ~buffer && (bs = bc % 4 ? bs * 64 + buffer : buffer,
        bc++ % 4) ? output += String.fromCharCode(255 & bs >> (-2 * bc & 6)) : 0
    ) {
      buffer = chars.indexOf(buffer);
    }

    return output;
  }
};

export default Base64;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just installed base-64 npm package ;) https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64

Comment: Yep, agree with @chemitaxis, imo better to use package rather then copy a code.Maybe you could update your answer with couple of options.

Comment: Using packages means install all unnecessary things to project while you could just copy the necessary code for one specific need. It is not the right way and not better. It is worst. Thanks for the answer btw.

Answer (score 119):

That's the ways I fixed it. As [@chemitaxis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1147273/chemitaxis) suggests, add base-64 module from NPM:

```
npm i -S base-64
```

Based on it, I propose a couple of ways to use it:

### Importing it in files you need it

Then, you can import 'encode' and 'decode' methods using aliases, this way:

```
import {decode as atob, encode as btoa} from 'base-64'
```

Of course, using aliases is optional.

### Polyfill way

You can set `atob` and `btoa` as global variables on React Native. Then, you won't need to import them on each file you need it. You have to add this code:

```
import {decode, encode} from 'base-64'

if (!global.btoa) {
    global.btoa = encode;
}

if (!global.atob) {
    global.atob = decode;
}
```

You need to place it at the beginning of your `index.js`, so that it can be loaded before another file uses `atob` and `btoa`.

I suggest you to copy it on a separate file (let's say base64Polyfill.js), and then import it on `index.js`

Comment: this code work fine but In release apk, it doesn't work. Any idea to fix it ??

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you. I was able to use this to decode a JWT:
`const [encodedHeader, encodedBody, signature] = token.toString().split(".");` 
`const decoded = JSON.parse(atob(encodedBody));`

Comment: @RaikumarKhangembam did you manage to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 27):

The main part of your question has been answered, but I see there's still some uncertainty about why it works with remote debugging enabled.

When debugging remotely, the JavaScript code is actually running in Chrome, and the diffs to the virtual dom are being communicated to the native app over a web socket.

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment

`atob` and `btoa` are available in the context of the browser, and that's why it works there.

When you stop debugging, though, the JavaScript is again interpreted in a process on your device or simulator, which doesn't have access to functions that are provided by the browser.

Comment: this. I encountered a difference in execution when I (by my mistake) used native js sort function in a wrong way. The array was sorted differently with and without js debugging, so I guess every part of code that can produce unexpected results is susceptible to this.