# Base64-encoding in a BigQuery User-defined function

Tags: javascript, base64, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

BigQuery uses Javascript for its user-defined functions. Input and outputs that are `BYTES` in BigQuery are mapped to and from base64-encoded strings in Javascript.

BigQuery doesn't have the browser `window` object, so `atob` and `btoa` are missing. Is there an easy way to encode and decode in the Bigquery JS environment, or do you have to include a library for doing the mapping?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to include a library, but it's fairly straightforward once you get the JavaScript onto Cloud Storage, and you can use this approach for other common libraries that you want to import. I found an implementation in [a StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42833475/6253347), and I put these contents in a file named `btoa_atob.js`:

```
(function () {
  var chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';

  function InvalidCharacterError(message) {
    this.message = message;
  }
  InvalidCharacterError.prototype = new Error;
  InvalidCharacterError.prototype.name = 'InvalidCharacterError';

  // encoder                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  // [https://gist.github.com/999166] by [https://github.com/nignag]                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  btoa = function (input) {
    var str = String(input);
    for (
      // initialize result and counter                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      var block, charCode, idx = 0, map = chars, output = '';
      // if the next str index does not exist:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      //   change the mapping table to "="                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      //   check if d has no fractional digits                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      str.charAt(idx | 0) || (map = '=', idx % 1);
      // "8 - idx % 1 * 8" generates the sequence 2, 4, 6, 8                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      output += map.charAt(63 & block >> 8 - idx % 1 * 8)
    ) {
      charCode = str.charCodeAt(idx += 3/4);
      if (charCode > 0xFF) {
        throw new InvalidCharacterError("'btoa' failed: The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.");
      }
      block = block << 8 | charCode;
    }
    return output;
  };

  // decoder                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  // [https://gist.github.com/1020396] by [https://github.com/atk]                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  atob = function (input) {
    var str = String(input).replace(/[=]+$/, ''); // #31: ExtendScript bad parse of /=                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    if (str.length % 4 == 1) {
      throw new InvalidCharacterError("'atob' failed: The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.");
    }
    for (
      // initialize result and counters                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      var bc = 0, bs, buffer, idx = 0, output = '';
      // get next character                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      buffer = str.charAt(idx++);
      // character found in table? initialize bit storage and add its ascii value;                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      ~buffer && (bs = bc % 4 ? bs * 64 + buffer : buffer,
        // and if not first of each 4 characters,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        // convert the first 8 bits to one ascii character                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        bc++ % 4) ? output += String.fromCharCode(255 & bs >> (-2 * bc & 6)) : 0
    ) {
      // try to find character in table (0-63, not found => -1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      buffer = chars.indexOf(buffer);
    }
    return output;
  };

}());
```

Then I copied the file to my Cloud Storage:

```
gsutil cp btoa_atob.js gs://my-bucket/
```

Then I wrote a dummy function that uses it:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION Foo(b BYTES) RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE js AS """
var result = atob(b);
// ... process result of atob.
return result;
"""
OPTIONS (library='gs://my-bucket/btoa_atob.js');

SELECT Foo(b'\xa0b1\xff\xee');
```