# Nodejs Buffer.from(..) convert javascript react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have the following code in Nodejs:

```
Buffer.from(`${pwd}`, 'base64').toString('utf8')
```

I have to do the same thing in Javascript for React-native.

How can I do some advice?

Comment: Which part? `Buffer` or the string conversion?

Comment: Do what webpack and browserify do and polyfill it: [Other node core libraries](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#other-node-core-libraries) which uses [node-libs-browser](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser#readme).

Comment: If you just need to convert a string between base64 and utf8, you can probably just use [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#Appendix.3A_Decode_a_Base64_string_to_Uint8Array_or_ArrayBuffer).

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane: You know the code I wrote in the post, I have to do the same but in react-native, what Buffer.from does not find it for react-native, but I presume that if I remember the toString (...) function well, it accepts only numerical parameters in js.
So I have to do everything.

Comment: @zero298: What do you think of this could go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42833475/8024296