# React Native CouchDB/pouchDB app is not working in release apk

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, couchdb, pouchdb

i am trying to make simple dictionary project, i use CouchDB for remote server and use pouchDB for local.

and i use remote text file for pre loading data in local db.

This is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
...
import { localNoteDb, nameIndex, remote_url, remoteNoteDb } from '../const'

...
let handlerSync = null

class Home extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.state = {
            arrNote1: [],
            arrNotee: [],
            isLoading: false,
            text: '',
            count: 0,
            data1: 0,
            data2: 0,
            indicator: false,
            flagadd: false,
            notfoundFlag: false
        }
    }
    ....

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getListNoteFromDb();

    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.getListNoteFromDb();
    }




    syncDb = () => {

        this.setState({ isLoading: true });


        //here is my text file to pre load the data from remote amazon s3 text file
        localNoteDb.load('https://dictionary.s3.ap-north-14321.amazonaws.com/dumpdb.txt', { proxy: remote_url }).then(() => {


            localNoteDb.replicate.from(remote_url).on('complete', function () {
                console.log("DONE>>>>>>>")
            }).on('error', function (err) {
                console.log("ERROR>>>>>" + JSON.stringify(err))
            });
            var temp = localNoteDb.replicate.from(remote_url, {
                live: true,
                retry: true
            });
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
            return temp;

        }).catch((err) => {
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        });



    };

    getListNoteFromDb = () => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true })


        fetch("http://myipaddress:5984/dictionary")
            .then(Response => Response.json())
            .then(response => {
                localNoteDb.info().then((resp) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(resp))
                    //resp will contain disk_size
                    if (resp.doc_count !== response.doc_count) {
                        this.syncDb();
                    } else {
                        this.setState({ isLoading: false })
                    }
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log("ERROR<<<<<<" + err);
                });

            });

    }


    getListNoteFromDbText = (txt) => {

        this.setState({ text: txt, indicator: true, notfoundFlag: false })

        clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
            localNoteDb
                .allDocs({
                    include_docs: true,
                    attachments: true,
                    startkey: txt.toLowerCase(),
                    endkey: txt.toLowerCase() + '\ufff0'
                }).then(function (result) {
                    if (result.rows.length > 0) {
                        // handle result

                        this.setState({
                            indicator: false,
                            arrNote1: result.rows.slice(0, 10)
                        })
                        clearTimeout(this.timer);
                    } else {
                        this.setState({
                            indicator: false,
                            notfoundFlag: true
                        })
                    }


                }.bind(this))
                .catch(err => {
                    this.setState({ isLoading: false })
                    Toast.show(err.message)
                })
        }.bind(this),
            100
        );

    }

    renderItem = ({ item }) => {

        console.log("ITEMS....." + JSON.stringify(item));
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight
                underlayColor={'#98c5ba'}
                onPress={() => {
                    this.isAtCurrentScreen = false
                    this.props.addWordHistory(item.doc)
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailsMeaning', {
                        idNote: item.doc,
                    })

                }}
                style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginTop: 3, marginRight: 10 }}
            >
                <Text numberOfLines={1} style={{ color: '#29282A', margin: 5, fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular' }}>{item.doc._id}</Text>

            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }
    render() {
        return this.state.isLoading ? <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#f3fffc' }}><ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#ff6a00" /><Text>Fetching Data Please wait...</Text></View> : <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#f3fffc', zIndex: 1 }}><View style={{ marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 15, zIndex: 2, marginTop: -28 }}>
            <SearchBar
                placeholder="Type Here..."
                lightTheme={true}
                color='black'
                searchIcon={{ size: 30, color: '#3ea58d' }}
                inputStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
                inputContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white', height: 30 }}
                containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#3ea58d', borderRadius: 5 }}
                onChangeText={(text) => this.getListNoteFromDbText(text)}
                value={this.state.text}
            />
        </View>
            {this.state.text === '' ? <Text></Text> :
                (this.state.indicator ? <View style={{ flex: 1 }}><ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#ff6a00" /></View> : <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}><Text style={{ backgroundColor: '#98c5ba', textAlign: 'center', color: 'white', marginTop: 5, marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 15, borderRadius: 3, fontFamily: 'Roboto-Black' }}>RESULTS</Text>{this.state.notfoundFlag ? (<Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', color: 'black', marginTop: 50, fontSize: 21, fontWeight: 'bold', fontStyle: 'italic' }}>Not Found</Text>) : (<FlatList
                    style={{ backgroundColor: '#f3fffc', marginTop: 6 }}
                    data={this.state.arrNote1}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                />)}</View>)}
            <View style={{ marginTop: 1, position: 'absolute', bottom: 0 }}>
                <AdsBanner />
            </View>
        </View>

    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        wordHistory: state.addHistory.wordDetails
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addWordHistory: (product) => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_WORD', payload: product })
    }


}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Base64 code, i put the link in index.

```
import {decode, encode} from 'base-64'

if (!global.btoa) {
    global.btoa = encode;
}

if (!global.atob) {
    global.atob = decode;
}

process.browser = true
```

It works fine in debug mode but not in release mode.

I had same issue as this

[React Native atob() / btoa() not working without remote JS debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829838/react-native-atob-btoa-not-working-without-remote-js-debugging)

Everything work fine in debug mode by putting base64 code, but when i do `./gradlew assembleRelease` and test the apk, data not able to load.

In release apk also it show same issue as above.

Is it related to base64 issue or any other issue? 
Please Help.
Thanks.

Comment: The problem as stated is extremely vague.  What errors do you get? Any?  "is not working" is far too broad.

Comment: The problem is only happen in release apk, dont know how to check the error in release apk app. In debug testing it's working fine.

Comment: Log exceptions.

Comment: add debuggable true in android/app/build.gradle,   i checked logcat in android studio ... cant see any errors exceptions nor warning.