# evaporate.js not sending to_sign from mobile device

Tags: reactjs, react-native, evaporate.js

I am working on an app that has web and mobile ui components.  We are using evaporate.js to call an endpoint that will return a pre-signed url for chunk uploading to aws buckets.  This concept works when used from react and it sends the `to_sign` querystring parameter to create the `pre-signed` url.  For some reason, when this code is run from react native the `to_sign` query string value is not getting passed to the endpoint.  What could possibly block the `to_sign` parameter from getting passed from evaporate, this same code is working for react app?  Here is the code we are calling from react native:

```
const uploader = Evaporate.create({
    signerUrl: config.SIGNER_URL,
    aws_key: config.AWS_KEY,
    bucket: config.BUCKET,
    awsRegion: config.AWS_REGION,
    cloudfront: true,
    xhrWithCredentials: true,
    computeContentMd5: true,
    cryptoMd5Method: (d) => btoa(sparkMD5.ArrayBuffer.hash(d, true)),
    cryptoHexEncodedHash256: sha256,
  });

  const uploadFile = (file, cb) => {
    setLoading(true);
    setUploadingError("");
    let newName = uuidv4();
    let extension = file.name.split(".");

    uploader
      .then((evaporate) => {
        evaporate
          .add({
            file,
            name: newName + "." + extension[2],
          })
          .then((res, err) => {
            if (res) {
              cb(res);
              setLoading(false);
            } else if (err) {
              setUploadingError("Something went wrong");
              setLoading(false);
            }
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setUploadingError("Something went wrong");
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

Not sure if this is a reach, but the mobile version does not supply a url for CORS as opposed to the url set on the CORS s3 admin screen, so could this possibly be a CORS issue?

Comment: Where should the `to_sign` query parameter come from? It isn't listed in the docs: https://github.com/TTLabs/EvaporateJS/wiki/Evaporate.create()

Comment: From what I can see when Evaporate.create promise is called, for my web version, internally, it is sending it when it calls the signerUrl to get the pre-signed url.  I can see it getting passed to my endpoint that is generating the pre-signed url.

Comment: Which version of `Evaporate` are you using? You can get the exact version in `package.json` or `package-lock.json`

Comment: "evaporate": "^2.1.4"

Comment: The web and mobile versions are using the same version.

Comment: I am getting the to_sign qs parameter for the pre-signed url endpoint from the web but not the mobile versions.

Comment: Wait so it creates a signed url to upload to S3, how do you known the `to_sign` parameter is missing if it's send to s3?

Comment: The logic seems to get triggerd when you invoke `.add`: https://github.com/TTLabs/EvaporateJS/blob/2.1.4/evaporate.js#L1865

Comment: My endpoint will create the pre-signed url.  Evaporate will call my endpoint and pass it the to_sign qs parameter.  Evaporate does not create the pre-signed url on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is because the btoa not work in react-native. Because react-native
use a different js engine with the browser. Some js code is executable in the browser but not in rn. Try to implement btoa by yourself.

There is a similar question [React Native atob() / btoa() not working without remote JS debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829838/react-native-atob-btoa-not-working-without-remote-js-debugging/42833475)